# How to write three constantly updating lines in terminal using curses?

Tags: python, curses

I have a program which needs to output three messages that are constantly changing. Number of connections, time elapsed, and refused connections.

I tried writing them with `'\r'` at the end of the string and printed newlines before the other ones started their own output loops thinking the return carriage goes back one line. but they all ended up in the first line overwriting each other.

I've seen similar questions and people were recommending using `curses` but i can't seem to get it to work. I try using `addstr()` instead of `print` or `sys.stdout.write()` but clearly i'm not doing it right because it ended up looking like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08T42.png) I also tried using `move(0,0)` after every `addstr` because i thought that maybe the coordinates are calculated from the last position of the cursor but the output looked the same as when i didn't do it

Here's my current code using `curses` -

```
from scapy.all import *
from curses import wrapper 
import argparse, random, socket, sys, time, os, threading, re, subprocess, curses

def main(target):
    try: 
        stdscr.clear()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()
        stdscr.keypad(1)

        #things regarding user agents and iptables

            for conn in range(args.connections):
                t = threading.Thread(target=sendPacket, args=(targetIP, args.port, targetHost,random.choice(userAgents)))
                threads.append(t)
                t.start()
                numConn += 1

                try:
                    lock.acquire()
                    stdscr.addstr(0, 0,'{0} Connections Established to {1} '.format(numConn,getIP(target)))
                    stdscr.refresh()
                    #sys.stdout.flush()
                finally:
                    lock.release()
            time.sleep(args.timer)  


        CloseWin()
        sys.exit()
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
        lock.acquire()
        stdscr.addstr (5,0,'Exiting {0}'.format(e))
        CloseWin()
        lock.release()
        sys.exit()

#functions that deal with resolving host and IP

def sendPacket(targetIP,targetPort,targetHost,userAgent):
    try:
        #building and sending the packet
        failPacket = 0
        lock.acquire()
        if synack is None:
            stdscr.addstr(1, 0, '{0} Connections refused'.format(failPacket))
            stdscr.refresh()
            failPacket += 1
            return

        #send final packet

        lock.release()
        return
    except Exception,e:
        CloseWin()
        #print e
        lock.release()
        return 



def MeasureTime():
try:
    lock.acquire()
    while True:
        stdscr.addstr(3, 0,'{0} Time elapsed'.format(time.time() - startTime))
        stdscr.refresh()
finally:
    lock.release()

def CloseWin():
try:
    lock.acquire()
    curses.nocbreak()
    stdscr.keypad(0)
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
finally:
    lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #args

    stdscr = curses.initscr()

    if args.debug == True:
        wrapper(OneConn(args.target)) #OneConn is the same as the main function except it only opens one connection, so the print is the same
    else:
        startTime = time.time()
        wrapper(main(args.target))
```

Also in addition to not writing correctly i can't seem to close it properly, when i use `ctrl+c` to try and get out it looks like it stops updating the print outs regarding the packet but the time still keeps going. and i can't figure out a way to stop it other than closing the terminal.

Tried adding locks per @martinaeu's suggestion and edited the post to show what i did. And the result was that i can only see the `time elapsed` being printed out and updated in the fourth line, can't see the other prints at all and still can't get out of the program without closing the terminal

Comment: At least some of the problems you're having may have to do with multithreading as there are multiple ones trying to use curses at the same time (logically at least). To successfully use it concurrently you may need to add a `Lock` object that each thread (include the main one) must acquire before using the curse API and release it afterwards.

Comment: @martineau Never worked with locks before so i read up on them and tried adding them how i thought it would make sense. edited the main post to reflect that

Comment: The way you're using the `Lock()` is a bit inefficient, and there may be a minor bug in how it's used in the threaded `sendPacket()` function. Suggest you do a little more reading about them and start using them as context managers via the `with` statement. This would eliminate needing most if not all the `try`/`finally` stuff (because `with` will make sure `release()` gets called regardless of whether there's an exception even if there are multiple `return` statements).

Comment: As for the original problem, I think the position arguments to `addstr()` are relative to the corner of screen they're sending output to, which means that each `sendPacket` thread needs to add/update information on a _different_ row for them all to visible. You could pass them the row (column isn't really needed here) position as additional  arguments to the function when each thread is created.

Comment: @martineau I want `sendPacket` to write it all on one line, just have the number of packets sent to change. At the start i thought that `addstr()` is relative to the corner of the screen, and i think the way i called the lines make sense, but it doesn't seem to work. Regarding the `lock()`, do i just replace all the `try/finally` stuff with `with lock:`? because i tried that and i'm pretty sure i did it right and it doesn't work

Comment: I think I understand what you want—namely to update what's already displayed on multiple lines/rows. To do that each thread needs to have a line/row "assigned" to it and it should always use that row in any calls it makes to `addstr()`.

Comment: hmm - more than just the try...finally blocks.  curses is used in several places, and concurrent access by different threads is going to produce bad results.  By the way, this should be a duplicate (curses+threads has been discussed several times).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `curses`, you can simply emit the raw codes to move the cursor back three lines.  This would be:

```
os.write(1, "\x1b[3F")
```

Be careful: the lines are not erased.  It shouldn't be a problem if the new lines that you print have the same length as the old ones (e.g. because they are formatted with something like `"foo: %10d"`).

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes (where "CSI" stands for "\x1b[" and the n is an optional number written in decimal).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, wasn't aware this was a feature. 

For `python3`, a bytes object is required, e.g. `os.write(1, b'\x1b[3F')`

Comment: the '3' in '3F' will be how many lines you want to go back, i.e. 4F is 4 lines